# Selenium clicks one time, but next click returns StaleElementReferenceException

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
import sys
import urllib2
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import string
import re

reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')

baseUrl = 'https://www.breastsurgeons.org/new_layout/membership/membersearch/index.php'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/Cellar/chromedriver/2.36/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get(baseUrl)
time.sleep(20)

for p in range(1,282):

    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'>>')]").click()
    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

After opening the baseUrl, I manually click agree and then search for a list of physicians to show up. I want to flip through the listing. Right now Selenium only clicks the first time by finding ">>". After which it stops and gives following error.

```
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'>>')]").click()


  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.11.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click


    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)


  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.11.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute


    return self._parent.execute(command, params)


  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.11.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute


    self.error_handler.check_response(response)


  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.11.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response


    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)


selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

In your program within the `for()` loop you are locating the `<a>` tag element with text as **>>** on a page and invoking `click()` and due to the `click()` event the *HTML DOM* changes. When your program iterates the `for()` loop for the second time perhaps the *WebElement* identified as `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'>>')]")` doesn't gets loaded but *Selenium* tries to refer the search from the previous iteration which have already turned **stale**. Hence you see **StaleElementReferenceException**.

### Solution

A convincing way to iterate the pages would be instead of :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'>>')]").click()
```

You can induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) in-conjunction with [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) clause set to [element_to_be_clickable](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) for the *WebElement* with the particular *Page Number* (e.g. **3**, **4**, **5**, etc) to be **clickable** as follows :

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'3')]"))).click()
```