# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document: tree recursion in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, recursion, treeview

I am trying to download web pages using python selenium.
There is a tree view on the left side and the content on the right side.

This is HTML of treeview. Of course, all sub menus are closed at first.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="./item2.html">item2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item3</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="./item4.html">item4</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item5</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="./item6.html">item6</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item7</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="./item8.html">item8</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item9</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="./item10.html">item10</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" onclick="openSubMenu()">item11</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="./item11.html">item12</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click an item, if it has a page link, it is linked to the right's `iframe` tag, if not, opens the sub-menu.

I used tree recursion to open all sub-menus.

```
def tree_recursion(self, tree_container):
    tree_branches = tree_container.find_elements(By.XPATH, './li')
    for tree_branch in tree_branches:
      time.sleep(0.5)
      tree_branch.find_element(By.XPATH, './a').click()
      try:
        new_tree = tree_branch.find_element(By.XPATH, './ul')
        if new_tree:
          tree_recursion(new_tree)
      except:
        continue
```

But it didn't work, Following error occurred.

```
File "...\run.py", line 105, in tree_recursion
    tree_branch.find_element(By.XPATH, './a').click()
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 433, in find_element
    return self._execute(Command.FIND_CHILD_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 410, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.75)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x00B66643]
        (No symbol) [0x00AFBE21]
        (No symbol) [0x009FDA9D]
        (No symbol) [0x00A009E4]
        (No symbol) [0x00A008AD]
        (No symbol) [0x00A00B30]
        (No symbol) [0x00A30FAC]
        (No symbol) [0x00A3147B]
        (No symbol) [0x00A264C1]
        (No symbol) [0x00A4FDC4]
        (No symbol) [0x00A2641F]
        (No symbol) [0x00A500D4]
        (No symbol) [0x00A66B09]
        (No symbol) [0x00A4FB76]
        (No symbol) [0x00A249C1]
        (No symbol) [0x00A25E5D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00DDA142+2497106]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E085D3+2686691]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00E0BB9C+2700460]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00C13B10+635936]
        (No symbol) [0x00B04A1F]
        (No symbol) [0x00B0A418]
        (No symbol) [0x00B0A505]
        (No symbol) [0x00B1508B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7607FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777D7A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x777D7A6E+238]
```

I've tried to solve this problem, but I didn't find any solution for it because it needs **dynamic selector** in three recursion function.

What is the best solution for the dynamic selector?

Or any other way to scrap this?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned *'all sub menus are closed at first'*. So everytime you invoke the `click()` method, sub-menus becomes visible i.e. the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) changes and more menu items gets visible within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

After each click as the HTML DOM changes but your program keeps on referring the previously found elements. As example, you program still tries to refer to *`tree_branch`* even after you have invoked click. Hence you see the error *`StaleElementReferenceException`*.

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussion on [StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44844879/7429447) in:

- [Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52075477/7429447)
- [Selenium clicks one time, but next click returns StaleElementReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49548851/7429447)

Comment: Thank you @undetected-selenium. You helped me to understand `StaleElementReferenceException`, and I solved the problem. It works well now.  `for idx in range(len(tree_branches)):
      WebDriverWait(self.browser, 30).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath + '/li[' + str(idx + 1) + ']' + '/a'))).click()` variable `xpath` is the xpath of current node. https://stackoverflow.com/a/34540096/14551577 Thank you again.